# reCaptcha not working on Safari with "prevent cross site tracking" setting enabled

Tags: safari, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, cross-site

We have a problem in safari that does not load recaptcha. We found out that it's related to `prevent cross site tracking` setting on safari website tracking setting (image below):

[image: Website tracking setting]

Now we are looking for a solution to resolve this problem without forcing users to disable this setting.

This is what we get on safari:

[image: Recaptcha error on safari]

and the console error on safari:

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

And the error only shows up when I load a subpage. Im getting this error and I don´t know why
`The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.`

It's not an error, just a warning that you browser does not support the `'strict-dynamic'` token. (guess you use Safari).

I guess that **subpage** is a some Google's iframe (oAuth2, reCaptcha, etc). That iframe publush it's own CSP wich contains the `'strict-dynamic'` token and this CSP was created in browsers backward compatibility mode (Google make such).

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I've been experiencing this problem for a long time, and none of the prior interventions did anything.  However, this one is the culprit. For the time being, I've disabled this check-box, and the problem cleared.

Thank you.

Dick
Charlotte